# Frogs and Toads

Tags: algorithm, prolog

I'm very new to Prolog and came across a logic riddle that seems easy to implement, but after spending 2 days searching online, I still can't wrap my head around how to solve it in Prolog.

Three frogs and three toads are lined up in the configuration illustrated in the Starting State figure below. The frogs are on the right and the toads on the left. By a series of valid amphibian moves you must transform the state to the Goal state, also illustrated below.

But the frogs and toads can only move in accordance with the following specification:

- Only one amphibian (i.e. frog or toad) can move at a time.
- Frogs can only move to the left and toads can only move to the right.
- Each move is ether a crawl or a hop.
- A crawl is a move to an adjacent empty space.
- A hop is a move to an empty space that is two spaces away from the starting space, such that the space between the start and end of the hop is occupied by another amphibian.
- Frogs can only hop over toads and toads can only hop over frogs.

[image: Illustration of the starting and goal states]

**Edit**

What I want to implement is all the possible moves that the frogs and toads can make, manually, I have solved this problem, but I want to implement it so the program resolves it while executing the least amount of moves.

Here is what I am trying to do:

**initial state: [frog1,frog2,frog3,gap,toad3,toad2,toad1]**

transition_1: [frog1,frog2,gap,frog3,toad3,toad2,toad1]
transition_2: [frog1,frog2,toad3,frog3,gap,toad2,toad1]

.

.

.

**final state:: [toad3,toad2,toad1,gap,frog1,frog2,frog3]**

Comment: Only stating a problem, without the code on which you cannot progress, is not the better way to get help on SO...

Comment: @CapelliC that is my problem, cannot find a source to learn how to write it properly, I am sure all I did makes no sense, so I did not post it.

Comment: This is basically an [automated planning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_planning_and_scheduling) problem, so it could be solved using a planning language like [PDDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planning_Domain_Definition_Language). I have seen several open-source implementations of PDDL in Prolog.

Comment: See e.g. the `searching` example in the Logtalk distribution: https://github.com/LogtalkDotOrg/logtalk3/tree/master/examples/searching This example implements a state-space search framework. Several similar problems there. Coding the problem you describe is mainly a question of defining initial state, goal state, and next state predicates and then using the provided search methods.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what you mean by "seems easy to implement?" Ideally include a pseudocode example related to any language you like.

Comment: @גלעדברקן I updated the question with more description

Answer (score 0):

I know this riddle in the following way. But I guess jumping frogs/toads are more reasonable than jumping camels:

> Two caravans of camels cross in a narrow valley.

Here is a simple solution, using brute force and the camel idiom, the former because the search space has no loops and is finite:

```
/* right facing camel advances */
move([0'>, 0' |L], [0' , 0'>|L]).
/* left facing camel advances */
move([0' , 0'<|L], [0'<, 0' |L]).
/* right facing camel jumps */
move([0'>, 0'<, 0' |L], [0' , 0'<, 0'>|L]).
/* left facing camel jumps */
move([0' , 0'>, 0'<|L], [0'<, 0'>, 0' |L]).
/* search move further right */
move([X|L], [X|R]) :- move(L, R).

find(X, X).
find(X, Y) :- move(X, H), find(H, Y).
```

It seems that there are two solutions:

```
?- find(">>> <<<", "<<< >>>").
Yes ;
Yes ;
No
```

Homework: Change the above code, so that it shows a list of movements.